# asp.net mvc calling ReportViewer to display report FOLDER (Not report)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, reportviewer

I have the ReportServer asp.net webform working when called from asp.net mvc....

First Question:
But what I am having trouble with is displaying a report folder contents...I am porting functionality over form windows ReportServer and the following works in Windows also
directly from the browser:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=%2fB.+TBS
```

But When I try to use this from asp.net embedded in asp.net mvc I get an error unless I 
supply the ReportServerUrl with the following: http://www.mydomain.com/ReportServer
I have tried

serverReport1.ReportPath = "/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=%2fB.+TBS";

as well as other variations on this and I can't figure out how to display the folder...

Second Question:  Currently I am NOT being prompted to login ... I have NOT set impersonation in web.config .... I would like to have the user enter their userId and password....How can I force this to happen.

Here is my current page_load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {


        ReportViewer1.ShowParameterPrompts = true;
        ReportViewer1.ShowToolBar = true;
        ReportViewer1.ShowRefreshButton = true;
        ReportViewer1.ShowCredentialPrompts = true;



        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
        ServerReport serverReport1 = ReportViewer1.ServerReport;

         //This works to display a report...        
         //    serverReport1.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://www.mydomain.com/ReportServer");
         //    serverReport1.ReportPath = "/B. TBS/B.2. Departments";

         //This works too...same thing ...getting ready to put into web.config...
                string url = @"http://www.mydomain.com/ReportServer";
                string ReportName = "B. TBS/B.2. Departments";
                serverReport1.ReportServerUrl = new System.Uri(url);
                serverReport1.ReportPath = string.Format("/{0}", ReportName);

         //This works in Windows, but not here...outputs..Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=utf-8', but expected 'text/xml'
         //      serverReport1.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://www.mydomain.com/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=%2fB.+TBS");

      //   serverReport1.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://www.mydomain.com/ReportServer");
      //   serverReport1.ReportPath = "/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=%2fB.+TBS";

    }
}
```

Here is my current asp.net webform:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ReportViewer.aspx.cs" Inherits="TBS.Etracs.Web.Main.Reports.Reports" %>


<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" 
             Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" 
             TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
    <div>

    </div> 
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <rsweb:ReportViewer  ID                    ="ReportViewer1"
                             runat                 ="server"
                             Width                 ="100%" 
                             Height                ="100%"
                             SizeToReportContent   ="True" >
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found out where my Confusion was coming from....

The ..../Reports/....    Interface is exposing the ReportManager Service from within the ReportService...

While the traditional ..../ReportService/.... is working with the ReportViewer service from within the ReportService.

For Windows (where I am porting functionality from) the application was using BOTH the ReportManager and the ReportService interface.... But I did not know that these were two different services....I thought they were both functions of the ReportViewer service and I could not figure out why the view of the folder was not working....

The windows application was also using the ReportExplorer (Client) application...which does not have a similar feature on the web side....

I figured out that I can do what I want to do by linking to the current ReportManager interface ... and this does not require me to use an asp.net ReportViewer control as a client side control.

What I have now is just a redirect to the ReportServer ... Eventually I will replace with an IFrame (or IFrame like) web page that will share a common master page with the asp.net mvc application so I can make the report server web pages have the same header and footer as the rest of the application.